# iOs 5 Safari new "reader" feature, how to use it for developers?

Tags: iphone, html, ios, safari, mobile-safari

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable iOS 5 Safari Reader on my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997918/how-to-enable-ios-5-safari-reader-on-my-website)

So iOS 5 Mobile Safari has this new reader feature but I don't understand how it works on my website and what I as a web developer can do to make sure a webpage is "Reader" compatible.

Does anyone know where I can find docs on this, I understand it's still in beta but there should still be docs somewhere. As far as I can tell by playing with it, its seems to be looking for RSS feeds? Can anyone elaborate?

Comment: I don't think Apple has announced anything yet. Are you in the Safari Developer Program? If you are, you may be able to find the relevant docs in Apple's site.

Comment: Isnt the iOS-5 features still under NDA?

Comment: Yeah am in the program but no luck so far :(

Comment: Then you'll have to wait, as this stuff is still under NDA and everything is still in early stages.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't really official documentation for it, but you just have to keep a good structure in your HTML. I've found some 3th party documentation here:
http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/safari-reader

For example, make use of heading tags for titles.

```
<h2>This is one item</h2>
```

You should then either use a DIV or SPAN to wrap your content in.

```
<span>This is the content that you would see in the reader</span>
```

What also seems to help is to use class names like "author", "content" or "article" for your content. It will be picked up by the reader. So you would get a result like this:

```
<h2>My Item</h2>
<span class="author">Some Name</span>
<span class="article">My content.</span>
```

I've seen websites without RSS feeds and still have the reader option, so that's not necessary.