# Programmatically open Safari in Reader mode

Tags: ios, cocoa, macos, safari, mobile-safari

Is it possible to programmatically open Safari and/or mobile Safari in Reader mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reader functionality appears to be derived, in part, from the [Readability project](http://www.readability.com/). It might be worth reading up on a few of the resources out there which look at reader in more detail. Some good starting points, and links to other resources:

- http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/safari-reader
- [How to enable iOS 5 Safari Reader on my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997918/how-to-enable-safari-reader-on-my-website)

With regards manipulating Safari / reader, I'm not aware of any relevant API offered by Apple, and I'd be surprised if they offered specific code to put a site in reader mode. After all, the option to invoke this functionality should really be user-initiated if one is going by standard human interface guidelines.

Answer (score -3):

If you have a URL, then you can use the *openURL* method of **UIApplication** which will open the URL for you.

Comment: That's not what he's asking. Christian wants to know if there's a way to manipulate Safari so that its "reader" mode (a method of seeing a web page stripped of all extraneous content and advertising) can be invoked **programmatically**.