# How to make web site iPad ready?

Tags: ipad, web

I have GitHub hosted site for FOSS project http://www.nodeclipse.org
and got iPad. With Safari browser for some site I can click small icon left of address bar and and only page main content will be shown (hiding all columns on the left or right that only nice to big screen)

**How to make web site support that convenient reading on iPad?**

If I just knew exact name for the feature I could have found, but so far I came only on general optimization for smaller screens.

Comment: You're looking for 'reader mode', see https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/safari-reader

Comment: That give more questions that answers. Would "container element" be enough? What is "container element" ?

Comment: I guess the answer is on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997918/how-to-enable-ios-5-safari-reader-on-my-website